# Partially match route in WebAPI Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing, attributerouting

Is there any way to match only the first part of a URL using WebAPI (attribute routing specifically). Something like a way to match multiple optional path components where the number is not known beforehand.

For example: `[Route("v{ver}/search/{remainingPath})]` matches the paths `v1/search/products` or `v2/search/customers/1234`.

I'd like to take advantage of WebAPI's great route matching framework, but the path components after `search` will not be part of the controller/action matching process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your route template to `[Route("v{ver}/search/{*remainingPath})]`?...here the `*` would allow any number of segments after the `search` segment to be matched to your route...

Comment: What parameter type is necessary to get a match? I've tried `string`, `string[]`, `IEnumerable<string>`, `List<string>`, and `object` and it always turns out null. I also get a 404 if I add more than one path segment. Do you have a link to documentation of this feature? It's pretty hard to Google for "*" but I might be missing something.

Comment: Name the parameter on the action to be `remainingPath` (of type `string`) and this parameter should now contain the rest of the path segments...

Comment: It doesn't work for me: [see here](https://gist.github.com/nemec/ed11f9632f3cfb7bd103). I can access `http://localhost:33378/v1/search/test/other/`, but `remainingPath` is still null and IIS 404's when I try to add more path segments (`http://localhost:33378/v1/search/test/other/path/`). NuGet says I'm using AttributeRouting.WebApi 3.5.6. Also, if I try to make `remainingPath` a non-optional parameter, it fails to find an action for the controller (at least it gets the controller right).

Comment: my bad the format should have been `{*remainingPath}` instead of `{remainingPath*}`...notice the position of `*`..

Comment: Brilliant! The trailing `*` looked analogous to the regex zero-or-more operator, which fits in this context, so I didn't even think to try the other way.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to override the route handlers to intercept the request and do custom routing. I've never done it, but it looks like you can implement the HttpControllerDispatcher and override the SendAsync method to change the request.

```
public class CustomRouteHandler : HttpControllerDispatcher
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //Your code here to change the route

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Check out the poster for a visual of what you can override in the web api pipeline.
http://www.asp.net/posters/web-api/asp.net-web-api-poster.pdf

Here's some more articles on routing that may help.
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions