# Web API partially (start with) match route in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing, attributerouting

How can I map multiple urls to one action method? For example `http://localhost:10000/api/ABC` and `http://localhost:10000/api/ABCDCD` will map to same action name because both starts with ABC. I can't add `ABC` and `ABCDCD` as routes because I would not know in advance what user will pass.

Here is my current method

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("~/api/ABC/")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetData()
{
}
```

I tried using [{ver}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251453/partially-match-route-in-webapi-controller) but it did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#complex-segments).

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("~/api/ABC{data}")]
public IActionResult GetData(string data)
{
    return Ok(data);
}
```

When you request `https://localhost/api/ABCEXAMPLE` the value of string `data` would be `EXAMPLE`. You can even do not use it if you don't want.

---

UPD:

The better solution is to use regex:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("~/api/{s:regex(^ABC.*)}")]
public IActionResult GetData()
{
    return Ok();
}
```

[image]